# Populate list from multiple database columns

Tags: android, sqlite, listview

Can anyone suggest the best way to populate a list from an sqlite database.  The database has multiple columns A, B, C, D, E, F, and multiple rows 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8,

I am trying to populate the list with the values from columns A, B, D, F, and row 1 or 2 or 3 or 4 etc... depending what rowid has previously been passed.

Comment: Could you elaborate? What do you mean by populate a list with values from columns. What kind of list do you want?

Comment: I currently have a listview populated from a single column in my database, on clicking the entry in thid activity i want to bring up a new activity containing a list (listview?) with each row of the list containing the contents of selected database columns (all from the same database row).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use SimpleCursorAdapter - http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SimpleCursorAdapter.html

If you want you could refer to this tutorial for beginners - http://coenraets.org/blog/android-samples/androidtutorial/

Comment: I currently have a listview populated from a single column in my database, on clicking the entry in thid activity i want to bring up a new activity containing a list (listview?) with each row of the list containing the contents of selected database columns (all from the same database row).

Comment: Thanks, the second tutorial was very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure I got the question right, Nevertheless

```
        Cursor mCursor = DatabaseHelper.fetchItems();   
        startManagingCursor(mCursor);       
        String[] from = new String[]{"column 1", "column 2", "column 3"};
        int[] to = new int[]{R.id.Row_TextView01, R.id.Row_TextView02, R.id.Row_TextView03};    
        SimpleCursorAdapter lists = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.row, mCursor, from, to); 
        setListAdapter(lists);
```

And the row.xml file is like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:orientation="vertical">
     <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Row_TextView01"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>  
     <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Row_TextView02"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>  
  <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Row_TextView03"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>  

</LinearLayout>
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: primpalpop, thanks for the code, I was alble to use parts of it to help write my code.